# Equivalent of use-expressions attribute in XML based Spring Security configuration to code based configuration

Tags: spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

How to enable the `use-expressions` option of the Spring Security configuration in a code based configuration? This option is needed to enable [Expression-Based Access Control](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/el-access.html) usage for Thymeleaf.

In the XML configuration it looks like this:

```
...
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >
   ...   
</http>
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this](http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/11/spring-security-java-config-preview-readability/) blog post, `use-expressions` is set to true when using the Java Configuration.

```
Comparison to XML Namespace
...
One difference is that Java Configuration uses authorizeUrls 
to specify use-expressions="true"
```

Hope this helps.