# how to set use-expressions= true in java config file instead on xml file in spring security

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to use spring security "authorize" tag in my jsp as below. But it is not working. As per my reading in some blogs i need to set use-expressions=true in security-config.xml. But I am using a java config file instead of a xml file. So how to set the use-expressions attribute to true in java config file?

Comment: This SO post might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698077/equivalent-of-use-expressions-attribute-in-xml-based-spring-security-configurati

Comment: Thank You. But I am not finding authorizeUrls() method in HttpSecurity class. All I find is authorizeRequests. But that is not working for jsp tags

Answer (score -1):

There are differences between spring security java configuration and xml configuration.One difference is that Java Configuration uses **authorizeUrls** to specify **use-expressions="true"**